# resizeNN in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm looking for a fast version of `cv::resize()`, I tried to dig in OpenCV source and found that function `resizeNN`, which I assume it uses ARM Neon.. I tried to test it, but the dst Mat has no data at all or I'm a confused with this function ? it is not even in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

there is cv::resize() [which calls cv::reserve() for most of the job],

in modules/core/src/matrix.cpp ~ L 599

---

and there is resizeNN( const Mat& src, Mat& dst, double fx, double fy )

in modules/core/src/imagewarp.cpp ~ L 355

(it's not even in the api, so that's probably a private impl function)

---

they look totally independant to me, i think, you want the first one.

Comment: @break I'm looking for a faster version of cv::resize().